# have two ffmpeg commands which work as expected I want to combind

Tags: ffmpeg

The first one

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -ss 0:06 -i "%%a" -i Logo.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=1920:-2,setsar=1[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

The second one

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -af "aeval='-val(0)':c=same" "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

Can someone help, I'm not expert in ffmpeg

Comment: Should the output of the combined command seek from 6 seconds of the MP4?

Comment: If it cut the first 6 second it will be great, do we need to remove the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the audio filter and remove `-c:a copy` since filtering isn't compatible with streamcopy,

`for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -ss 0:06 -i "%%a" -i Logo.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=1920:-2,setsar=1[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40" -af "aeval='-val(0)':c=same" -c:v libx264 "Logo\%%~na.mp4"`

Comment: thank you so much for help, now it's worked